# PreBuildEvent not reflecting in project dependencies

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have two C# projects, one of them, the library, contains a database file which is modified during PreBuildEvent. Its contents are correctly updated and available in bin\Debug folder of this library project.

The problem occurs because in the other project, the UI application, the database file is the same as before my changes in PreBuildEvent.

In the example below, I will use a text file (it behaves the same):

---

**ProjectLib.csproj**

- TextFile1.txt

  - Build action: Content
  - Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

PreBuildEvent:

```
echo test > $(TargetDir)TextFile1.txt
```

Contents of TextFile1.txt in ProjectLib\bin\Debug:

```
test
```

---

**Application.csproj**

Contents of TextFile1.txt in Application\bin\Debug:

```
"empty"
```

---

From where the database file is picked? From `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(TargetDir)`? **EDIT:** The database file is picked from `$(ProjectDir)`. You can see this executing the build using msbuild. At the end there is a target named `_CopyOutOfDataSourceItemsToOutputDirectory` and this shows the source as `$(ProjectDir)`.

Is there a way to modify the file in the PreBuildEvent - the file in library bin\Debug - and have it correctly output to application bin\Debug?

Comment: I solved this by getting the file from `$(ProjectDir)`. First, I added the file to the project with a different extension (.bkp) and then I added in PreBuildEvent a file copy. The bkp file is copied to the correct name. In project, I added a reference to both files (even if the correct one does not exist before build). For the bkp I set to None and for the other as Content.

Comment: I will leave the question open if someone comes with a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you designing your build system to have two separate projects overwrite a critical dependency?

Comment: Because the database file is a deliverable for both the library and for the sample application. But even if I change the database file to the same project as the library, the same error will occur when deploying the sample application.